# Deploying django project under sub-URL with Apache/FastCGi

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-fcgid

I am trying to deploy a django project under a sub-URL on hostgator hosting. Here is the tutorial I was following: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi

My index.fcgi looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/my_project_dir")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/my_project_dir/my_project/")
os.chdir("/home/my_project_dir/my_project/")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "my_project.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

And the .htaccess looks like this:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Both of these files placed in a sub-direcotry `/home/my_project_dir/public_html/dir/sub/` Problem is that when I try to access www.mydomain.com/dir/sub/ I get a 404 Resource not found error.

Answer (score 0):

grep for the 404 message in your access_log files, it will indicate whether the RewriteRule matched or not.

```
grep " 404 " access_log
```

either you will see

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2012:23:50:56 +0100] "GET /index.fcgi/XXXX HTTP/1.1" 404 123
```

or

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2012:23:50:56 +0100] "GET /XXXX HTTP/1.1" 404 123
```

the second ones indicates that the rewrite didn't match...

Comment: The rewrite does matches and I am getting this in error log:
`File does not exist: /home/my_project_dir/index.fcgi/the_url/`

Comment: make sure you can execute index.fcgi; `chmod +x index.fcgi`

Comment: it is executable, I can run it manually ./index.fcgi

Comment: what happens in the logs and response, if you call `http://www.mydomain.com/index.fcgi` ?

Comment: response prints the contents of fcgi file. I am not sure why it is not executing it

Comment: make sure its executable for all users `chmod o+x index.fcgi`

Comment: it is already executable for all users. changing permissions no effect

Comment: I suspect then, that fastcgi is not configured correctly.